# With expression non evaluation

Tags: agda, dependent-type

I am trying to define a `CoList` without the delay constructors. I am running into a problem where I use a with expression but agda doesn't refine the type of a subcase.

```
module Failing where

open import Data.Unit
open import Data.Empty
open import Data.Maybe
open import Data.Nat
open import Data.Vec hiding (head ; tail ; map ; take)

record CoList (A : Set) : Set where
  coinductive
  field
    head : Maybe A
    tail : maybe (λ _ → ⊤) ⊥ head -> CoList A
open CoList

nil : ∀ {A} -> CoList A
head nil = nothing
tail nil ()

cons : ∀ {A} -> A -> CoList A -> CoList A
head (cons x xs) = just x
tail (cons x xs) tt = xs

take : ∀ {A} -> CoList A -> (n : ℕ) -> Maybe (Vec A n)
take l zero = just []
take l (suc n) with head l
...                 | nothing = nothing
...                 | just x = map (λ xs → x ∷ xs) (take (tail l {!!}) n)
```

The type of that hole is `maybe (λ _ → ⊤) ⊥ (head l)` but because of the with expression I would expect the type to be `⊤`. I expect this because I withed on the `head l` and in that case `head l = just x`. If I try to fill the whole with `tt` agda mode gives me the following error:

```
⊤ !=< (maybe (λ _ → ⊤) ⊥ (head l)) of type Set
when checking that the expression tt has type
(maybe (λ _ → ⊤) ⊥ (head l))
```

I answered the question below, so now I am curious is there a better way to encode this list without the delay constructor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can think of `with t` as replacing `t` by whatever you match against, in the types of both function arguments and the goal. However, `head l` does not appear in your goal type when you perform the `with` — a goal whose type involves `head l` only appears later, once you have partially constructed the solution. This is the reason why your initial attempt doesn't work.

The `inspect` idiom, as demonstrated in your answer, is indeed the usual solution for this sort of problem.

As for encodings of coinductive types with 'more than one constructor', there are two (closely related) approaches that I'm aware of:

1. A mutual inductive/coinductive type:

   ```
   data   CoList′ (A : Set) : Set
   record CoList  (A : Set) : Set

   data CoList′ A where
     [] : CoList′ A
     _∷_ : A → CoList A → CoList′ A

   record CoList A where
     coinductive
     field
       unfold : CoList′ A

   open CoList

   repeat : ∀ {A} → A → CoList A
   repeat x .unfold = x ∷ repeat x

   take : ∀ {A} → ℕ → CoList A → List A
   take zero    _ = []
   take (suc n) xs with unfold xs
   ... | [] = []
   ... | x ∷ xs′ = x ∷ take n xs′
   ```
2. Taking the cofixpoint explicitly:

   ```
   data CoList′ (A : Set) (CoList : Set) : Set where
     [] : CoList′ A CoList
     _∷_ : A → CoList → CoList′ A CoList

   record CoList (A : Set) : Set where
     coinductive
     field
       unfold : CoList′ A (CoList A)

   open CoList

   repeat : ∀ {A} → A → CoList A
   repeat x .unfold = x ∷ repeat x

   take : ∀ {A} → ℕ → CoList A → List A
   take zero    _ = []
   take (suc n) xs with unfold xs
   ... | [] = []
   ... | x ∷ xs′ = x ∷ take n xs′
   ```

Answer (score 3):

One solution I found is to use the inspect idiom. Apparently with abstractions in agda don't propagate equalities. The [inspect](http://agda.readthedocs.io/en/latest/language/with-abstraction.html) idiom makes the equality obvious.

```
data Uncons (A : Set) : Set where
  Nil : Uncons A
  Cons : A -> CoList A -> Uncons A

uncons : ∀ {A} -> CoList A -> Uncons A
uncons l with head l | inspect head l
uncons l | nothing   | _ = Nil
uncons l | just x    | [ p ] = Cons x (tail l (subst (maybe (λ _ -> ⊤) ⊥) (sym p) tt))

take : ∀ {A} -> CoList A -> (n : ℕ) -> Maybe (Vec A n)
take l zero = just []
take l (suc n) with uncons l
...               | Nil = nothing
...               | Cons x xs = map (λ rest → x ∷ rest) (take xs n)
```